# Having trouble with matching type in Haskell (generateTrees)

Tags: haskell, tree

i am sitting with two guys on a haskell project and we have quite a bit of trouble with the following code:

I try to give you all the necessary information:

From the module Types.hs:

```
class Game g s | g -> s where
  findPossibleMoves :: Player -> g -> [(s,g)]
  identifyWinner :: g -> Player -> Maybe Player 

data Player = Player1 | Player2 deriving (Eq,Ord)
```

and here is the code we want to implement:

```
generateGameTree :: Game g s => g -> Player -> Tree (g,Player) s
generateGameTree g p = ([ Node ((snd x),p) [] | x <- (findPossibleMoves p g )])
```

So we try to get this thing compiled but it wont work . It might be important to know how a tree looks like so thats the definition:

```
data Tree v e  = Node v [(e,Tree v e)] deriving (Show,Eq,Ord)
```

We allready know, that the returntype of the function and our returntype doesn't match, but there must be another mistake in this.

We would appreciate any help , thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to split this operation into two smaller ones:

A generic `unfold` function first which, given a seed of type `s` and a function computing one layer of tree generates a whole tree by repeatedly calling itself on the next generation of seeds. This definition would have type:

```
unfold :: (s -> (v, [(e,s)])) -> s -> Tree v e
unfold next seed = _fillThisIn
```

You can then use this function to define your `generateGameTree`. The intuition behind using `unfold` is that the `seed` of type `s` represents the state of the game and the function `next` computes the possible new states after one move (together with the `v` and `e` "outputs").

Comment: Thank you very much we have found a solution now!

Answer (score 0):

To whom it may interest:

This works now without compiler error:

generateGameTree g p = Node (g,p) [ ((fst x),generateGameTree (snd x) (nextPlayer p))  | x <- (findPossibleMoves p g) ]